# Optimize function to take less time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a column named comment in the student table, I added some random characters across these encrypted data (adding noise), I'm querying the encrypted data so I should clear this noise through a function called remove (this function removes every fourth letter from the encrypted string). I created a scalar-valued function named `Remove` which cleans some noise from the encrypted data. This function works correctly, but it takes a long time to execute, about 40 seconds (with a 1000000 records). So I tried with an inline table-valued function, but it returned no data.

An example of the data being queried is:

```
"!,T%OMAZTAA#:R$Tt$TNM)CRJEI6ZN/=#8AoABE1NAYABE-PI!0VAAj#G)sV)C]IZN/`)V
```

The scalar valued function is as follows

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Remove] (@encrypt VARCHAR(255))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @word VARCHAR(200) = '';

    WITH Numbers AS (
        SELECT TOP (LEN(@encrypt)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS N
        FROM master.dbo.spt_values
    )

    SELECT @word += SUBSTRING(@encrypt, N, 1)
    FROM Numbers
    WHERE (N - 1) % 4 <> 0;

    RETURN @word;
END;
```

When using in a select statement it works fine and returns data, but takes 40 seconds.

```
SELECT Id, COMMENT 
FROM student 
WHERE dbo.Remove(COMMENT) like '%N/#8AABEN`AABEPI!VAA#G)V)CIZN`)V';
```

However, by creating an inline table valued function as

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Remove] (@StringData VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
    WITH Numbers AS (
        SELECT 1 AS N
        UNION ALL
        SELECT N + 1
        FROM Numbers
        WHERE N < LEN(@StringData)
    )
    SELECT
        word = STRING_AGG(SUBSTRING(@StringData, Numbers.N, 1), '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Numbers.N)
    FROM Numbers
    WHERE (Numbers.N - 1) % 4 <> 0
);
```

and applying

```
SELECT Id, COMMENT
FROM student
CROSS APPLY dbo.[Remove](COMMENT) AS r
WHERE r.word LIKE '%N/#8AABENAABEPI!VAA#G)V)CIZN)V';
```

It gives me error

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion

by trying to add `OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);` as

```
SELECT Id, S_L_COMMENT_idx
FROM LINEITEM2 s
CROSS APPLY dbo.[Removess](S_L_COMMENT_idx) AS r
WHERE r.word LIKE '%N/#8AABENAABEPI!VAA#G)V)CIZN)V'
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

it takes 4 minutes and also no results are returned.

Using:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64) Sep 24 2019 13:48:23 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0  (Build 22621: )

Comment: Well in your second attempt `COMMENT LIKE '%N/#8AABENAABEPI!VAA#G)V)CIZN)V';` should actually be `r.word LIKE '%N/#8AABENAABEPI!VAA#G)V)CIZN)V';`

Comment: @Dale K , when trying with r.word LIKE '%N/#8AABENAABEPI!VAA#G)V)CIZN)V'; it givess error as "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion."

Comment: comment column in student table includes encrypted data like "!,T%OMAZTAA#:R$Tt$TNM`)CRJEI6ZN/=#8AoABE1N`AYABE-PI!0VAAj#G)sV)C]IZN/`)V" it works on 1000000 record

Comment: this function removes every fourth letter from the encrypted string and compared with encrypted substring

Comment: Well, technically the function did get faster

Comment: You have to add `OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)` just before the `;` of the query

Comment: SELECT Id, COMMENT
FROM student
CROSS APPLY dbo.[Remove](COMMENT) AS r
WHERE COMMENT LIKE '%N/#8AABENAABEPI!VAA#G)V)CIZN)V' OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0); takes more than 4 minute and still running and finally no data returned

Comment: SQL Server isn't designed for string manipulations so it's not something it's pretty good at. I'd hazard a guess that 1/4 the string manipulations would be 4x faster with something like `... SELECT @encrypt = STUFF(@encrypt, N, 1, '') FROM Numbers WHERE (N - 1) % 4 = 0 ORDER BY N DESC; RETURN @encrypt`

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  SQL Server 2022 introduced the `GENERATE_SERIES()` that would eliminate the need for a CTE. You also might see a slight performance improvement if you grab 3 characters at a time - `SUBSTRING(@StringData, N * 4 - 3, 3)` for N in {1, 2, 3, ...} with a special case to extract the last fragment.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0 <X64> (Build 22621: )

Comment: @SalmanA, sorry cant understand what you mean

Comment: I tried more, but usless

Comment: The function Remove works fine, when applied with a table, no data is returned

Comment: Of course there's no need for a function like this. Since you're using the `LIKE` operator you can just include the `_` wildcard character in the appropriate character positions, e.g.: `WHERE COMMENT LIKE '%N/#_8AA_BEN_\`AA_BEP_I!V_AA#_G)V_)CI_ZN\`_)V'`

Comment: That was suggested in their duplicate question, @AlwaysLearning . For some reason they seem to have forgotten all the advice they got there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve performance and avoid the recursion limit, you can use a numbers table to generate the sequence of numbers instead of a recursive CTE

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Remove] (@encrypt VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
    WITH Numbers AS (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS N
        FROM master.dbo.spt_values
    )
    SELECT
        word = STRING_AGG(SUBSTRING(@encrypt, Numbers.N, 1), '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Numbers.N)
    FROM Numbers
    WHERE (Numbers.N - 1) % 4 <> 0
      AND Numbers.N <= LEN(@encrypt)
);
```

I have used, ROW_NUMBER() over the spt_values table to generate a sequence of numbers. This should be more efficient than the recursive approach.

please use dbo.prefix before the function name:

```
SELECT Id, COMMENT
FROM student
CROSS APPLY dbo.[Remove](COMMENT) AS r
WHERE r.word LIKE '%N/#8AABENAABEPI!VAA#G)V)CIZN)V';
```

Comment: yes, it runs with me and takes only 18 second,(Perfect) very thanks for you

Comment: Using @TNs suggest of substringing 3 chars at a time would be quicker still.